# split("/") URL from the 2nd one to the end

Tags: javascript, jquery

The url looks like

```
www.my.com/store/all-books/nove/book-name/
```

How can I get the url from /all-books/nove/book-name/ to the end ?

I use something like

```
like var v1 = split("/")[3];
like var v2 = split("/")[4];
like var v3 = split("/")[5];
```

then combine

```
v1 + v2 +v3;
```

looks long and not well.

Is there an easy way to achieve ? thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Try `val = x.match(/(.*?\/){3}(.*)/)`

Comment: @ArunPJohny how about making that an answer with an explanaition of the Regular Expression?

Comment: What is your actual desired output?

Comment: @JonP not that good in explaining regex... that is why posted it as a comment

Comment: Simple and clean: `const url = 'www.my.com/store/all-books/nove/book-name/';
const urlNew = url.split('/').slice(3, -1).join('/');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may use this :

```
var str = "www.my.com/store/all-books/nove/book-name/";
var res = str.replace(/(?:.*?\/){2}/, '');
console.log(res);
```

you can mention the number inside the `{}` I have mentioned `2` because I want everything after the 2 slashes

If you want the slash then just put `'/'` instead of `''` in the second line of the code, it will replace the match with the slash, thus giving you the resulting `/` in the beginning.
like this:

```
var res = str.replace(/(?:.*?\/){2}/, '/');
```

Comment: then it is upto the OP to decide what number he wants to keep inside those curly braces, 2 is for 2 slashes, I guess he will figure it out

Comment: Great solution! However, it excludes the leading slash: `/all-books/nove/book-name/` and gives: `all-books/nove/book-name/`

Comment: ohhif you want the slash then just put `'/'` instead of `''` in the second line of the code, it will replace the match with the slash, thus giving you the resulting `/` in the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javascript example:

    `var url="http://example.com/page/example"`

Now you can use replace method given below:

    `res = url.replace(/^(http:\/\/)?(.*)\.([a-z]+)/i, '');`


    `res=/page/example`

Now you can split with `split()` function

    `array = res.split("/")
    array[0]=page
    array[1]=example`

It replaces http,https and subdomains also.

Hope that helps.

Comment: how do you think this is an answer to OPs question

Comment: its capable of replacing anything, just put the number of slashes you want it remove as number inside curly brace, if http:// is present then just change the number to 4 instead of 2

Comment: OK. Cool. Good answer btw.

Answer (score 0):

Quick, dirty & regex free:

```
var url = "www.my.com/store/all-books/nove/book-name/"
var arrParts =url.split("/"); 
arrParts.splice(0,2); //Remove the two first parts;
var final = arrParts.join(" "); //Replace the space if needed with another separator
console.log(final);
```

[Fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/NmhGF/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do this is by use of the array method shift as follows.

```
var url = "www.my.com/store/all-books/nove/book-name/",
    urlParts = url.split('/'),
    newUrl;
urlParts.shift();
urlParts.shift();
urlParts.unshift( '' );
newUrl = urlParts.join('/');
```

`.split('/')` converts the url into an array using '/' as a separator

`.shift()` used twice to discard the first two elements of the array

`.unshift( '' )` adds an empty string as the first element of the array

`.join('/')` combines the remaining elements using '/' as a separator

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/9mqX4/)

Answer (score 0):

Was trying to solve this myself and found the answer from @jon-p to be the cleanest and easiest to understand.  Took it one step further by chaining everything together...

```
const url = 'www.my.com/store/all-books/nove/book-name/';
const urlNew = url.split('/').slice(3, -1).join('/');
```

That `urlNew` result only includes slashes in between the array items, which is what I needed.  To include opening and trailing slashes as well, you can do it like this:

```
const urlNew = '/' + url.split('/').slice(3, -1).join('/') + '/';
```

For explanation of slice() and its start and end values, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice  Note that I chose not to use splice()